# Multiple redirects from .htaccess - include root, but exclude subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm very unfamiliar with .htaccess and I've tried a lot of solutions posted in other threads, but I'm still stuck:

I have three sites:

- ronde-vormen.nl (corporate site)
- rond.cool (used for short urls)
- avenir.rond.cool (client site on subdomain)

On corporate site, urls can be quite long, e.g. `http://ronde-vormen.nl/diensten/webdesign/`.

I'd like to manually "create" shorter links via .htaccess, for example:

`rond.cool/web -> ronde-vormen.nl/diensten/webdesign`

or

`rond.cool/video -> ronde-vormen.nl/diensten/film-animatie`

I'd also like the root to redirect:

`rond.cool -> ronde-vormen.nl`

To achieve this, I had the following entered in .htaccess:

```
<!-- OLD .htaccess -->

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule .* / [L]
</IfModule>

Redirect 302 / http://ronde-vormen.nl/
Redirect 302 /web http://ronde-vormen.nl/diensten/webdesign/
Redirect 302 /film http://ronde-vormen.nl/diensten/film-animatie/
```

Troubles started when I created the subdomain. I've tried different things, which resulted in the following:

- subdomain also redirects to corporate site
- subdomain/web also redirects to webdesign-page on corporate site
- my custom redirects all point to corporate site root

Currently, my .htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=avenir.rond.cool [NC]
  RewriteRule .* / [L]

  Redirect 302 /film http://ronde-vormen.nl/diensten/film-animatie/
  Redirect 302 /web http://ronde-vormen.nl/diensten/webdesign/
</IfModule>
```

Now the root doesn't redirect, and custom paths are redirected when placed after the subdomain url as well.

I'm completely stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated... To summarize, I'd like to:

- redirect rond.cool to ronde-vormen.nl
- redirect custom paths
- exclude subdomain from redirecting altogether

Comment: 1) apache version? 2) do you have access to apache .conf files?

Comment: I really don't know. Issued a ticket with provider. Don't seem to have access to .conf.

Comment: Still, these are 3 separate websites? If you, for example, place `.htaccess` in the root of rond.cool, there is no way it will perform redirection from avenir.rond.cool to ronde-vormen.nl

Comment: Unfortunately, that's exactly what it does. So if I add the following redirect:

`Redirect 302 / http://ronde-vormen.nl`

Even `avenir.rond.cool` is being redirected to `ronde-vormen.nl`.

Comment: Do you use FTp to upload your files and have 3 separate FTP accounts?

Comment: Files are uploaded through SFTP, .htaccess was edited directly from DirectAdmin control panel.